# Area and time adjusted counts

Tags: time-series, count-data, spatial, ecology, adjustment

In 2019 I went to a site and counted 4 species of birds. The size of the site was 130 hectares and I spent a total of 54 hours counting the birds. The peak counts of the 4 bird species are presented in column B of the below table.

In 2020 I went back to the same site and counted the 4 species of birds and peak counts are in column C of the below table. However, in 2020 the size of the site had been reduced to 60 hectares and I only spent a total of 30 hours counting the birds.

I want to present area and time adjusted counts of the 4 bird species. My current approach is to present area adjusted counts (column D) and time adjusted counts (column E) separately.

Is it possible to present a single combined area and time adjusted count?

[image]